# Metro Style Application code file missing ReadLine feature?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I started programming a small "Metro Style" project in Visual Studio 2011, the one that was released in Windows Developer Preview. It combines XAML for the design and C# (in my project) for the code-behind.
  System.Console.WriteLine  ----> System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine,
  System.Console.ReadLine  ----> ?.........

So are these features actually missing / disabled
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regard to `Console.*`: In Windows 8 Metro there is no such concept like a console *window*. Methods related to a console make no sense. According to the API reference on dev.windows.com ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx ) `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` is available. The supported platforms do list Windows 8 Consumer Preview, so I assume this feature isn't yet available on the Developer Preview. I would recommend that you update to the latest build avaiable. Remember: The Developer Preview was in a very early stage and plenty of things have changes since then.

Comment: I would rather blame that MSDN article neglecting to mention that API is not available in WinRT - since it is generic to all platforms. Console class is not available in Win8 CP.

Comment: If what you want to do is display debug output inside your app, probably these guys may help you: http://www.moderncomponents.com/products/ConsoleClass/index.php, basically they're trying to develop a compatible Console replacement in Metro